# DoCmd.OpenForm takes a long time to trigger the Form_Load Event, says query running (Access 2016)

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have a Menu Form. When the User selects the button 'Main' it opens the form 'MAIN' as seen in the code below
Code:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

DoCmd.OpenForm "MAIN"

End Sub
```

The form should ideally leave the DoCmd statement and hit the MAIN Form__Load event immediately. The issue is it takes a few seconds for the code to reach the beginning of MAIN_Load and I am unsure why. Inbetween this time the bottom of Access says 'Calculating . . .' and 'Running Query', although there is no code that requires a query to run when this is called. The RecordSource of MAIN is "SELECT * FROM APN_Status" which is just a table, no query involved. Does it just take a while cause my form is complicated (navigation control with multiple pages, some with navigation controls themselves.)

How can I figure out what is happening between this event??

Comment: The RecordSource of your form in fact **IS** a query. And yes, if your form is "complicated" and contains several pages with multiple controls,maybe comboboxes that also have RecordSources, it might take a little time to "load" the form into memory until it can be seen as an *object* that can be manipulated via vba code.

Comment: To further Wolfgang's comment, you likely cannot determine much more about what's happening, because (to my knowledge) Access provides no hooks to its internal processes.  The object properties and event handlers are about all you got.  The status bar messages are a bonus that gives you a peak into what it's doing in the mean time.  The database engine is not like other advanced DBM's with profilers and tracers.  Likewise, the Access programming interfaces are based on antiquated COM interfaces and automation.

Answer (score 0):

> The form should ideally leave the DoCmd statement and hit the MAIN
>   Form__Load event immediately. The issue is it takes a few seconds for
>   the code to reach the beginning of MAIN_Load and I am unsure why.

No. It should hit the *OnOpen* immediately, then load the form. Loading the form means reading the record source(s) of the form, its subforms, and controls.

And *a few seconds* is certainly what to expect for this process.